# Eliminating Left Recursion

Tags: context-free

Hello I have the above Context Free Grammar and I try to eliminate the left recursion so I can pass it to a tool. Any techniques I've read so far doesn't help me so a little help would be appreciated.

```
exp  ->   num | exp op exp | (exp) 
op    ->   + | - | * | /
```

I don't have the slightest idea on how to proceed. The only technique I've seen on the internet is to transform a CFG where the symbol appears once with another one and not twice or anything like below.

```
foo->foo a
     | b
```

which can be transformed:

```
foo-> a bar
bar-> b bar
    | epsilon
```

Comment: You need to define the precedence rules.

Comment: Did you search on this site?  in a textbook?  This is well-covered in standard textbooks, and there are many other questions on this site that ask a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a grammar $ G=(V,\Sigma,P,S)$
You can eliminate left recursion with the following algorithm:

Let  $ A \rightarrow A\alpha_1 | A\alpha_2|...|A\alpha_n$

be the left recursions of a variable $A$, and
$ A \rightarrow \beta_1 |\beta_2|...|\beta_m$ such that each $ \beta_i$ doesn't starts with $A$ (meaning $\beta_i \notin A\left \{ V \cup \Sigma \right \}^{*}$

We will construct a new grammaer $G'=(V\cup \left \{ B \right \} , \Sigma, P_1, S )$ by replacing all the left recursion derivations of $A$ with the following rules:

$A \rightarrow \beta_i \: |\:  \beta_i B$ for $1\leq i \leq m$, and

$B \rightarrow \alpha_j \: |\:  \alpha_jB $ for $1\leq j \leq n$

You can show  that $L(G) = L(G')$

Applying this algorithm on your grammar yeilds the following rules:

$ exp \rightarrow num \: |\:  num\: B \: |\:  (exp) \: | \: (exp)\:  B $

$ B \rightarrow op \: exp \: | \: op\:  exp \: B $

$op \rightarrow + \: |\:   - \: |\:  * \: |\: \:  / $ (as before)

(Note that your example is wrong, it should be that $foo \rightarrow b \: \: bar$)

Comment: Yes , the example was a mistake on the rush I changed it. Thx for your answer! You also have a mistake. What is A?

Comment: Should be exp. Fixed it